# Android Studio freezes when take screenshot

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working on mac and my `Android Studio (3.0)` **freezes when take screenshot of device from `logcat`.** Just freezes and can't do anything finally force `Android Studio` to quit. I couldn't find anything about this issue around. Is there anyone else who faces this issue?

Comment: Could you include the screenshot you get(if it gets saved)?

Comment: Command, Shift, 4 takes screenshots of anything on Mac

Comment: As it is written as bold can't take screenshot of connected device from logcat. Not from mac. No screenshot saved, android studio freezes, responds to nothing

Comment: @tosbaa have you figured this out, I have been having the same issue with my Android Studio lately.

Comment: Has anyone fixed this? I have the same issue

Comment: @Val Okafor Sorry I'm writing after a long time. At that time i couldn't figured it out. Have you figured it out? or have you ever tried the answer by Devavrata ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and android studio was freezing for me when ever I try to take screenshot of take video recording, then I tried this.

When ever you take screenshot either camera or video.

When the dialog in android studio shows destination where it will save your file, change it to any other folder/location then pre-selected one.
Now click on save. It will save and work fine.

I tried the above and its working fine.